# How do you link one of your nav bar buttons to a sidebar that becomes visible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three buttons on top of my webpage. The Contact Me button is suppose to open a sidebar on the left side that is invisible until Contact Me is clicked. However, I can't make my sidebar appear when clicking Contact Me.

An example would be this: http://www.andrewmart.in/
When you click Contact, the sidebar appears.

Here is the three buttons for the home page:

```
<div class="nav">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a class="navbar" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="navbar" href="#tagline">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a class="navbar" id="contacts" href="#sidebar">Contact Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the sidebar that remains invisible until Contact Me is clicked:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul class="sides">
    <li class="side"><a class="things"href="header"> Home</a></li>
    <li class="side"><a class="things"href="#tagline"> About Me</a></li>
    <li class="side"><a class="things" href="#footer"> Contact Me</a></li>
  </ul>
  <footer>....</footer>
</div>
```

Here is the JQuery for toggling the sidebar invisible to visible:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#contacts').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visble');
  });
});
</script>
```

Lastly, the CSS for the Sidebar Menu:

```
#sidebar{
  background: #151718;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  top: 0px;
  transition: left  0.3s  linear;
}
#sidebar.visible{
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spelling of the `.visible` class is wrong. Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a10d9hpf/

On another note, I would also use `preventDefault()` on your click function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#contacts').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

Since you're not passing the value of `href` to your script to determine which element `id` is targeted when executed.

Answer (score 0):

In your JQuery `$('#sidebar').toggleClass('visble');`your visible is spelt wrong.